# What species do mutants belong to? Are they still Homo Sapiens?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Mutants have X-genes which give them superpowers, but they aren't fully separate from normal humans. In the *Days of The Future Past* movie, sentinels were targeting even normal humans who had a chance of having the mutant gene passed on to their children, grandchildren, or great grandchildren. Meaning that normal humans who can reproduce with other normal humans can have X-genes in suppressed form. But, what happens when X-genes get active? Do mutants remain homo sapiens?

There are lots of possibilities:

- They can reproduce with normal homo sapiens. Meaning they are still homo sapiens.
- They can reproduce with each other. Meaning mutants are a different species.
- They can only reproduce with other mutants who have the same superpowers. Meaning there are many species of mutants.
- They can't reproduce. Meaning they are like mules and aren't part of any species.

Which one is true?

Answers from the movies and comics are allowed.

Comment: When the first movie talked about human-being evolving every five thousand years, I always understood it as mutants being the "next phase"

Comment: There are plenty of trans-species hybrids that are fertile and interfertile; https://revistapesquisa.fapesp.br/en/when-hybrids-are-fertile-3/

Comment: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Homo_superior

Comment: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mutant_Cross-Breeding

Comment: I like your question and the way you frame it in biological terms, though I would reject the idea that mules have no species. But then, "Answers from movies and comics both are allowed" renders your question ambiguous, because bold statements found in fiction may not have this scientific basis. Suggest you clarify your request to ask either for evidence in the comics or movies that addresses the issue of reproduction, OR a statement in the comics or movies that doesn't necessarily address this point.

Comment: @Umbrella Corporation  You question is flawed.  It is true that the definition of a species in biology is:  "a group of living organisms consisting of similar individuals capable of exchanging genes or interbreeding. The species is the principal natural taxonomic unit, ranking below a genus and denoted by a Latin binomial, e.g. Homo sapiens."  But there are many examples of hybrid children of different species.

Comment: @Umbrella Corporation  The flaw in your question is the definiition of a species, which is the usual definition in biology but ignores the many examples of hybrids of different species.  The true scientific definition of a species would no doubt be much longer and more complicated.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Hybrids are either infertile or their next generations are infertile. Otherwise, they could be used to combine two species into one. There's actually no other attribute to differentiate. If you look at different breeds of dogs, they are significantly different from each other and yet they belong to same species because they can reproduce with each other. Ability to reproduce is logical point to define species because this one attribute protects the genome across time. If two species can cross-breed without any restriction, I'd call them wrong species.

Comment: @M.A.Golding I quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species): `A species is often defined as the largest group of organisms in which any two individuals of the appropriate sexes or mating types can produce fertile offspring, typically by sexual reproduction.`

Comment: In X-Men, there's a lot of talk about "homo superior" as if they are a different species, but there's also a lot of inconsistencies with how biology actually works.  Could it be that "homo superior" is in-universe propaganda?  i.e.  classifying the two groups (mutants and regular people) as separate species would serve to "other" the opposing group, and make it easier to justify oppressing them.

Comment: In the x-men comics, humans and mutants can have offspring, some of whom may be mutants and some humans. I would say that mutants and humans are the same species. Especially as the mutant theme in Marvel Comics is that of race relations. And all the human minor variants are still human.

Comment: When trying to define "species" I recommend people learn about "ring species".  Also, some species don't reproduce sexually at all, or only some of the time.  It really is more complicated than "these can all interbreed".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On Marvel [Earth-616](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-616), mutants are classified as *homo sapiens superior*, sometimes shortened to *[homo superior](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Homo_superior)*.

[New X-Men Vol 1 #114](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/New_X-Men_Vol_1_114)

[image: New X-Men v1 114 003]

Mutants can reproduce with normal humans, resulting in offspring which may fall into either category. [Wolverine](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/James_Howlett_(Earth-616)) has fathered several children with normal human women, producing mutants in some cases ([Daken](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Akihiro_(Earth-616))) and normal humans in others ([Gunhawk](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/William_Downing_(Earth-616)), [Saw Fist](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Saw_Fist_(Earth-616)), [Shadowstalker](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Shadowstalker_(Earth-616)) and [Fire Knives](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Fire_Knives_(Earth-616)) of [the Mongrels](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mongrels_(Earth-616))).

[Wolverine: Origins Vol 1 #28](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wolverine:_Origins_Vol_1_28)

[image: Wolverine - Origins 028 002]

[Wolverine Vol 4 #14](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wolverine_Vol_4_14)

[image: Wolverine v4 014 019]

It's also possible for the offspring of two mutants to be a normal human, as in the case of [Graydon Creed](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Graydon_Creed_(Earth-616)), the son of [Sabretooth](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Victor_Creed_(Earth-616)) and [Mystique](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Raven_Darkholme_(Earth-616)).

[Uncanny X-Men Vol 1 #301](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Uncanny_X-Men_Vol_1_301)

[image: Uncanny X-Men v1 301 004]

Answer (score 7):

They can reproduce with normal human beings.  The mother of Magneto's children Quicksilver and the Scarlet Witch was a normal human being.  Hence, they are still *homo sapiens*.  (According to the comics.)

Furthermore, many mutants have had children with other mutants whose powers bore no relationship with them.  This inter-fertility shows that particular powers are not breaking off into separate species.

Comment: Parenthood and genetics can change fast in the marvel world. The current status of Quicksilver and Scarlet Witch since Uncanny avengers Vol 2 # 3 is that they were ordinary humans babies, with no relation to Magneto, that was kidnapped and experimented on by the High Evolutionary. This makes them enhanced humans, but not mutants. A better example would be David Haller AKA Legion. He is the son of the mutant Charles Xavier and the human Gabrielle Haller.

Comment: It's a pretty well-worn trope in the Marvel Universe and most other comic book universes that a wide variety of sapient aliens, creatures, or entities that are either humanoid in shape ,or can assume a humanoid shape can viably interbreed with humans.